# Covariate flips association in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, stata

I have a model in which if I run the dependent (binary) variable with an independent (binary) variable, I get a strong positive correlation (OR around 4). However in the multiple regression model with a couple of other variables, this same variable now has a negative correlation (OR around 0.3).

Can someone simply explain what may have happened in the model? Is it because the other variables in the model are so much more correlated with the dependent variable that this specific variable flips it's association from positive to negative?

Thank you.

Comment: that could be well the reason. checkout `graph matrix` to see the pairwise correlations among your variables

Comment: Thank you, that's a command I haven't used before. I did: graph matrix dependent_variable independent_variable1, independent_variable2 etc. and this is what I got: http://prntscr.com/pfxh74

I've pointed with an arrow to my dependent variable. I'm not sure how to read this?

Comment: OK, you have binary variables throughout, Then a scatter plot is not of great use. You could introduce one additional confounder after the other in order to observe which one causes the coefficient to flip. Then, you may just do a cross-tab to investigate the bivariate relationship. Btw, what model do you estimate?

Comment: Thank you, so I've found the culprit. The model is a logistic multiple regression for life quality (better/worse) on a set of independent variables such as concentration difficulties, memory problems, self esteem etc.  Running it one variable at a time yields a positive relationship for each variable (higher OR of having reduced life quality if you also have one of these symptoms). Doing what you said earlier shows that concentration problems seem to be confounding the results as the model flips after introducing it. So we conclude: (new comment inc)

Comment: That concentration problems are confounding the model and therefore we leave it out. But what do I do with the variable concentration problems, then?